# How to loop across columns to calculate intersection of values in wide format data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a wide-format dataset that looks like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B |  |  |
|  | F | C | D |
| E |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Now, what I would like to do is to calculate the count of the values for all columns where both column C and that specific column are not null. So for instance for A and C, the value would be 0, the value for B and C would be one and so on, basically the intersection and to get this value as a row at the bottom for further manipulation. I would be grateful for any help on this.

So far what I have used is

```
clmn=list(df) 

for i in clmn: 
  df.loc('Intersection')=df[['Column C',i]].notna().all(1)
```

It does not turn up an error, but the 'Intersection' row has only NA values. So I am assuming it is a syntax error. I would want a loop through all the columns since there are 200+ columns. Perhaps I could use indexing instead but I am not aware of the syntax for referencing the columns in such a scenario.

Comment: 1- please provide the output of `df.to_dict()`, 2- please provide the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&`  with conversion to a numpy array for broadcasting, then `sum`:

```
counts = (df.notna() & df['Column C'].notna().to_numpy()[:,None]).sum()
```

Output:

```
Column A    0
Column B    1
Column C    1
Column D    1
dtype: int64
```

As a new row:

```
out = pd.concat([df, counts.to_frame(name='count').T])
```

Output:

```
      Column A Column B Column C Column D
0            A        B      NaN      NaN
1          NaN        F        C        D
2            E      NaN      NaN      NaN
count        0        1        1        1
```

Used input:

```
nan = float('nan')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': ['A', nan, 'E'],
                   'Column B': ['B', 'F', nan],
                   'Column C': [nan, 'C', nan],
                   'Column D': [nan, 'D', nan]})
```